# Dice rolling probability.

Tags: probability, dice

A die (6 face) is thrown 3 times. What is the probability that the second and third rolls are larger then the first roll.

Thank you

Comment: second + third roll > first roll or do you mean second>first and third>first

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are fairly new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are so far; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them write their answers at an appropriate level.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the first die has 6 possibilities.
It can roll a 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6
If it rolls a 6, there is no chance of a higher roll

A 5 has a 1/6th chance of higher

A 4 had a 2/6th chance of higher

A 3 has a 3/6th chance of higher

A 2 had a 4/6th chance of higher

A 1 has a 5/6th chance of higher

For both the second and the third one to be higher than the first, we have to roll them (2&3) and they both need to be higher, so for each on, the chance of higher is squared.

If the first roll is X then the chance that both the next ones are higher is Y

X=1 Y=25/36

X=2 Y=16/36

X=3 Y=9/36

X=4 Y=4/36

X=5 Y=1/36

X=6 Y=0

The Y values are the chance of doing this with each first roll. Each first roll has a 1/6 probability of happening, so we have to divide the Y's by 6 before we add them

(25+16+9+4+1+0)/216

55/216

There is a 55/216 chance of getting the second two rolls higher than the first roll

Answer (score 2):

*D* is the number of sides of the dice (maybe 6 on standard dice) so

$$P=\frac{1}{D}\sum_{k=1}^{D-1}\left(\frac{D-k}{D}\right)^2$$

Comment: Each result has a $\frac{1}{D}$ chance of occurring, so you are missing a factor of $\frac{1}{D}$.

Comment: @PerryIverson, ty, I didnt noticed, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E$ denote the event you mention and let $X$ denote the result of the first
roll. Then:

$$P\left(E\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{6}P\left(E\mid X=i\right)P\left(X=i\right)$$

Here $P\left(E\mid X=i\right)$ denotes the probability that the event happens under condition that the first result is $i$.

The second and third roll must then result in a number that exceeds $i$ so we come to: $$P\left(E\mid X=i\right)=\left(1-\frac{i}{6}\right)^{2}$$

Also it is clear that: $$P(X=i)=\frac{1}{6}$$ for each $i\in\{1,\dots,6\}$ so we end up with:
$$P\left(E\right)=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{i=1}^{6}\left(1-\frac{i}{6}\right)^{2}=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{i=1}^{5}\left(1-\frac{i}{6}\right)^{2}$$

Counting in opposite direction is handsome here and leads to: $$P\left(E\right)=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{i=1}^{5}\left(\frac{i}{6}\right)^{2}=\frac{1}{216}\sum_{i=1}^{5}i^{2}=\frac{55}{216}$$

Comment: This is perfectly correct. Sadly, I think the notation is confusing for what may be an early level math student. It still gets an upvote from me though.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify between Laertes' and Asimov's solutions, here is a Sage simulation of this:

```
N=1000000
count=0
for i in range(N):
    dice1 = ZZ.random_element(1,7)
    dice2 = ZZ.random_element(1,7)
    dice3 = ZZ.random_element(1,7)
    if dice2>dice1 and dice3>dice1:
        count = count+1
print count/N.n()
```

Output:

```
0.254369000000000
```

This agrees with Asimov's solution: $\frac{55}{216} \approx 0.255$, but disagrees with Laertes' solution: $\frac{75}{432} \approx 0.174$.

Comment: Thanks for doing a simulation to very mathematical claims. Although this isn't a mathematical answer, but an experimental one, it helps point out which mathematical answer is correct.